# jQuery, AJAX - Triggering wrong functions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making a form submit with jQuery's AJAX. I'm having several form's using AJAX like this:

```
$('#newUser').submit(function() {
var dataString = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLogin",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(returnedData){

        if(returnedData){
            $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
        } else {
            $('.sideBarNewUserWrap').fadeOut();
        }

    }
});
return false;
});
//
```

and then I am having another one like this:

```
$('#addLookup').submit(function() {
var dataString = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLookup",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(returnedData){

        if(returnedData){
            $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
        } else {
            window.location.href = "";
        }

    }
});
return false;
});
```

And for some reason, when I wan't it to trigger the #newUser it's triggering the #addLookup. If I remove the #addLookup, there's no AJAX OR jQuery running for #newUser (the browser is just refreshing if I click on "submit").

The forms look like this:

```
<form method='post' action='#' id='newUser'></form>
```

or

```
<form method='post' action='#' id='addLookup'></form>
```

How can this be? I've been looking at the same code for 2 hours now, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

**Update**

The #addLookup is only triggered if the 2 forms are on the same page. If the #newUser is standing alone on a page AJAX's triggering the right function.

**The full HTML**

```
<form method='post' action='#' id='addLookup'>

    <div id='tilfojOpslagClose'><img src='/includes/images/design/btn/closeWindow-btn.png'></div>

    <div class='successMessage'></div>
    <div class='errorMessage'></div>


    <div id='tilfojOpslagHeader'>
        <input type='text' name='lookupHeader' id='lookupHeader' value='Skriv en overskrift'>
    </div>

    <div id='tilfojOpslagExpand'>

        <div style='float:left;'>
            <label>Præsentations tekst (bliver vist på forsiden)</label> 
                <textarea name='lookupSubHeader' id='lookupSubHeader' maxlength='100'></textarea>
        </div>
            <span id='lookupSubHeaderCharsLeftOutput'>Du mangler <strong>50</strong> tegn</span>

        <div style='float:left;width:618px;margin:3px 0 0 0;'>
            <textarea name='lookupContent' id='lookupContent' style='height:100px;'></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id='tilfojOpslagBottom'>
            <div id='tilfojOpslagSubmit'><input type='submit' value='Opret mit opslag'></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

*And for #newUser*

```
<form method='post' action='#' id='newUser'>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ny bruger</legend> 
                <label>Brugernavn</label>
                    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' placeholder='Brugernavn vil forekomme på siden, som et alias'>
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <label style='color:#f00;font-size:8px;'>Ja, du skal skrive en gyldig e-mail. Du modtager et aktiverings link.</label>
                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' placeholder='E-mail - en del af dit login'>
                <label>Adgangskode</label>
                    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='Adgangskode - en del af dit login'>
                <input type='hidden' name='salt' id='salt' value='<?=uniqid(mt_rand())?>'>
                <input type='submit' value='Opret mig'>

                <div class='errorMessage'></div>
                <div class='successMessage'></div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?if($_SESSION['loggedIn']){?>
    <form action='' method='' id='addLookup'>
<?} else {?>
    <input type='submit' value='something'>
    </form>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Show the full HTML + code please

Comment: Just a question, HOW are you triggering the form posts? Where is the submit / button / anchor elements triggering the post located?

Comment: I hope those two forms are not **nested**...

Comment: @gdoron I have no idea of how to paste code not-nested into stackoverflow. im sorry.

Comment: The the full HTML **+ code** as is.

Comment: It works fine for me [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8jXt/)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar It's not a mislead, since the problem was what FarligOpptreden wrote as an answer.

Comment: oh thats gr8.. I might misunderstood the comment written by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes in from the SUBMIT button behaviour. A specific submit inside a form will only post the form that contains it. I compiled a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfQKJ/) that illustrates it. If you trigger a submit button that's not contained in a form, neither of the forms will post. If you trigger a specific submit button that's inside a specific form, only THAT form will be posted.

Al alternative might be to manually post both forms by attaching an OnClick event handler to the submit buttons...

Comment: From how I understand your answer: A submit button inside af specific form will trigger the form id's function. And that's how I got it already, so I don't understand why it's not working?

Comment: No...  That's exactly how your code is **wrong**. see the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8jXt/) from his code

Comment: I got it now. It's working. I think I was misunderstanding this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kolind. Your submit button is inside the `form`. I can't really understand how does it help your case.

Comment: @Kolind: Like I said, the submit button will only ever by default trigger it's container form's POST method. You can't expect it to automatically trigger all other form posts on the page. Like I also suggested, you can add an OnClick behaviour to each submit-type input on the page to manually trigger the POST action of both (or all) forms on the page.

Comment: Pleasure! Hope you get your form-posting woes sorted out soon... :)

Answer (score 1):

try using `preventDefault` to cancel the submit event also you can write single handler for both form. try this

```
$('#newUser,#addLookup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do="+id,
       data: dataString,
       success: function(returnedData){
           if(returnedData){
               $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
           }else{
               // include as per your need
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't get your problem exactly, but it seems that you are doing a POST with a parameter being passed in URL (which is supposed to ge GET). So there seems a conflict. It might be the mother of all problems.

```
type: "POST",  
url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLookup",
```

Comment: You can use datastring in POST request!